# How to handle a button press (Desktop Application)

Tags: c++, winapi, button, desktop-application

I am making a desktop application, and I got it to display a button. Now what I am trying to do is somehow handle the button press, but I do not know how. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("First Desktop Application");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 500,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
        L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
        L"Test2",      // Button text 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
        10,         // x position 
        100,         // y position 
        100,        // Button width
        20,        // Button height
        hWnd,     // Parent window
        NULL,       // No menu.
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Test");

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Here your application is laid out.
        // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!"
        // in the top left corner.
        TextOut(hdc,
            5, 5,
            greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        // End application-specific layout section.

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is a Windows Desktop Wizard project on Visual Studio 2019. I just want it to do something simple like display some text on the screen or something when the button is pressed.

This is what the window looks like:

[image]

Comment: [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `BUTTON` is clicked, it sends a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) notification message to its parent window.  You would simply handle that message in your `WndProc()`, eg:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        ...

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
            {
                // LOWORD(wParam) is the button's ID
                // HWND(lParam) is the button's HWND
                // do something with them as needed...
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }

        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is explained in the [`BUTTON` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons) on MSDN:

[Button Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-messages)

> #### Handling Messages from a Button
>
> Notifications from a button are sent as either [WM_COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-command) or [WM_NOTIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify) messages. Information about which message is used can be found on the reference page for each notification.
>
> For more information on how to handle messages, see [Control Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/control-messages). See also Button Messages.
>
> #### Notification Messages from Buttons
>
> When the user clicks a button, its state changes, and the button sends notification codes, in the form of [WM_COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-command) messages, to its parent window. **For example, a push button control sends the BN_CLICKED notification code whenever the user chooses the button.** In all cases (except for [BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcn-hotitemchange)), the low-order word of the `wParam` parameter contains the control identifier, the high-order word of `wParam` contains the notification code, and the `lParam` parameter contains the control window handle.